# link converter system not working correctly php

Tags: javascript, php, regex

i copied a code from web in which hashtags,mentions and links are converted from text to links this is that code

```
function convert_to_links($msg){
$final_message = preg_replace(array('/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/',
'/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9_]+)/i'), array('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', '$1<a href="users2?tag=$2">@$2</a>', '<b>$1</b><a href="hashtag?hashtag=$2">#$2</a>'), $msg);
return $final_message;
}
```

now my problem is that when i create a link it is connected to my localhost first  for ex if i type www.youtube.com it becomes contest.local/www.youtube.com & this is not letting the user to go to the link can anyone help me with this problem

ps: rest of the system is working fine i.e mention and hashtag system i am having problems only with links

Comment: Seems to me your forgetting Http:// in front of the url causing links to become relative instead of absolute

Comment: can you plzz edit the code and show me @patrick

Comment: The code is fine. It looks for **http://...** or **https://...**  in the string itself for conversion links: Example: `echo convert_to_links("Check out my great site - http://example.com")`

Comment: @Jamie_d, the code is not fine... if - per the OP's example - the string "Check out my great site -  www.example.com" is entered (missing https?), it will not be added to the resulting conversion and thus will be interpreted as a relative link (the result is: `Check out my great site - <a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a>`)

Comment: Let me rephrase. The code is fine for converting a sub-string which contains an absolute URL, which is what the function is intended to do.

Comment: Indeed. But OP wanted to convert www.youtube.com to a full working link... so he needs to either change the regexp (this one goes beyond my expertise at the moment, plus I’m working on my phone), but he could look in the direction of after the conversion to add http(s) to all full links that don’t have it yet...